# S3 Bucket referencing old code/api? Angular 5

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3

so I’m hosting my angular 5 site on and S3 bucket with Cloudfront. It has a ‘https’ secure domain. I used to use a non-secure api from Anguar as the backend, and when I tried to log in from the AWS hosted domain, I got the error:

```
zone.js:2019 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://app.my_app.io was 
loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 
'http://my_old_api.com/api/v1/account/auth'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

That made sense, so I swapped my Angular app to use a secure api instead, say, ‘'https://my_new_api.com/api/v1/account/auth'’. I rebuilt the app and uploaded the contents to the bucket, but I am still getting essentially the same error in my console when I try to log in, even though the old api is no longer referenced anywhere in my app.

So my question is, does AWS S3 bucket reference a cache, or have some sort of lag, or something that would cause it to be looking at my old code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront will cache it. The idea of using CloudFront is it would copy/cache the S3 contents into the local zone from where it is requested hence reducing latency for the end user.

You will need to invalidate the contents you want refreshed. If you go into the CloudFront console you should be able to do it.

1. Go to the CloudFront Console.
2. Click the Distribution ID of the CloudFront record.
3. Select Invalidations tab
4. Create an invalidation - and select what resources you want to invalidate. You can use wildcards here so maybe invalidate everything.

That should make CloudFront refresh all contents.

[image]